# Add/Remove Class from DIV in ServiceNow

Tags: jquery, servicenow

I have a `DIV` like the one below:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 form-field input_controls">

</div>
```

I want to change `col-xs-6` to `col-xs-12`. I attempted this with the below code:

```
$('div').removeClass("col-xs-6 form-field input_controls").addClass("col-xs-12 form-field input_controls");
```

But I am getting an error stating :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeClass' of null.

I am not a front end guy, so jQuery is beyond my scope.

Comment: wrap your code in DOM ready event.

Comment: Wasn't able to reproduce the issue https://jsfiddle.net/0f2wuk9u/

Comment: 4 Equal answers and anybody suggest you don't need to remove all classnames if you are going to add it again like `form-field input_controls` just remove the one you want and add the one you want

Comment: So apparently this does not work the way I was thinking it was going to work in our platform (ServiceNow). document.ready does not appear to be a function that can be called. Any one have ServiceNow experience with front ends?

Comment: For everyone who says to put it in a function that runs when the page is loaded - you're not wrong, but even if you execute and it doesn't find a match, the result of `$('div')` won't be null - it will be an empty jQuery object. It just wouldn't function, rather than throwing an error.

Comment: With that said, the script posted should never throw that error, unless `$` isn't actually jQuery. Try going to your browser console and type `$ === jQuery` and see if that returns true. If not, then `$` isn't actually jQuery, and you'll need to deal with that accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I was using the correct code for jQuery, however, the platform ServiceNow assigns jQuery to `$j` variable so it does not conflict with other jQuery prototypes. The code I was able to use and execute correctly is below:

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    if($j('div.col-xs-6.form-field.input_controls').hasClass('col-xs-6')){
        $j('div.col-xs-6.form-field.input_controls').removeClass('col-xs-6').addClass('col-xs-12');
    }

});
```

Comment: Personally, I use `jQuery` everywhere instead of `$` - it's more verbose, but it does handle those rare scenarios where some joker reassigns `$` to something else. Or, you could wrap your script in a function to take back the `$`, like `(function($) { $("div").show(); })(jQuery);`, although that does make things weird to read, where `$` means two different things depending on context.

Comment: Take a look to **[The right way to use jQuery with ServiceNow](https://jylertones.com/blog/2013/05/the-right-way-to-use-jquery-with-servicenow/)**.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `document.ready` function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div').removeClass("col-xs-6 form-field input_controls").addClass("col-xs-12 form-field input_controls");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your DOM structure is not ready when your javascript executes. So, you need to add a ready event:

```
$(function(){
  $('div').removeClass("col-xs-6 form-field input_controls").addClass("col-xs-12 form-field input_controls");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to remove all of the classes and add them again, the following should suffice:

```
$(function(){
    $('div').removeClass('col-xs-6').addClass('col-xs-12');
});
```

jQuery will append the class `col-xs-12` at the end of the div element.